# Sort based on values including key names

Tags: javascript, sorting

So, I'm trying to make a code which sorts the entries of an object based on a value including the key of a different entry.
An example:

```js
const object = {
    second: "this should go second because it mentions first",
    third: "this should go third because it mentions first and second",
    first: "this should go first because it mentions no other entry"
}

Object.entries(object).sort(([keyA, valueA], [keyB, valueB]) => /* here is my problem */);
```

I really can't figure out how to make a sort which achieves this goal so that's why I ask here.

**EDIT**

I'll try to make my goal more clear

I'm trying to sort a bunch of files based on dependencies so that I can bundle them together into one big file without certain files trying to call something which comes after it.

An example for this would be:

**NoDependency.js**

```js
class NoDependency {

    randomValue;

    constructor() {
        this.randomValue = 1;
    }

}
```

**ADependency.js**

```js
class ADependency {
    
    static randomValue = new NoDependency().randomValue;
}
```

And in this case the bundler will have an object which has the file name (without .js on the end) as the key and the code as the value. What I want is that it can be bundled together without it being in a order which will cause undefined errors.
(Also this has to be dynamic and this is without relying on import statements)

Comment: I don't understand the logic you want. The phrases are self-defeating, since the first values really mentions both "first" and "second", and the second one also mentions "third". Please give more clear examples.

Comment: Basically, whenever one of the entry values includes the key name, in this case first, second or third. it will put it behind whatever has this name. I'm making this to bundle a bunch of scripts together into one file without making static values try to call something which is added after it

Comment: Yes, but your example is confusing, like I wrote above. Please provide a good example.

Comment: please give an an real example of what you want to achieve or you entry will be closed

Comment: made an edit if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const object = {
  second: "this should go second because it mentions first",
  third: "this should go third because it mentions first and second",
  first: "this should go first because it mentions no other entry"
}

// we'll need these a few times
const keys = Object.keys(object);

// let's find the dependencies to each key.
// initialize them all with an empty array, so I don't have to deal with null-checks.
const dependencies = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, []]));

for (let key of keys) {
  const value = object[key];

  for (item of keys) {
    // find for every key, which **other** keys it mentions.
    if (item !== key && value.includes(item)) {
      // for every match, add the other key, and its dependencies to the current key
      dependencies[key].push(item, dependencies[item]);
    }
  }
}

// now that all dependencies cross-reference all other dependencies 
// and their dependencies, and their ... 
// we can flatten that list and remove duplicates
const sorted = Object.entries(dependencies)
  // for conveniance we also add the value at the second place 
  // that way this result doubles as a list of Object.entries()
  .map(([key, deps]) => [key, object[key], new Set(deps.flat(99))])
  // it should be enough to sort by the length of the dependency-list
  // but if necessary, we could check in a second step wether the key from a is in the dependencies of b or vice versa
  .sort((a, b) => a[2].size - b[2].size)

console.log("sorted", sorted);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(sorted));
```

Comment: @SMJS this solution also has a flaw: it doesn't deal with circular references. It doesn't even blow up *(like in an infinite loop)* since `flat(99)` is capped at 99 levels of depth *(you might want to increase that number if you deal with a lot of files and your dependency trees may be deeper; the resulting Set() should only contain strings, no more arrays)*

Comment: I'm aware, however I don't expect it to go that deep and circular stuff shouldn't work to begin with